# disable /feed/ for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, feed

Our custom post type posts have an extra feed in their source code:

`www.example/post-type/post/feed/`

I want to remove the extra `/feed/` from our CPTs, as they generate 404s.

From the [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) function reference, I've tried adding `'rewrite' => array('feeds' => false),` to:

```
register_post_type('templates',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Templates' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Template' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Template' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Template' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Template' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Template' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Template' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Templates' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Templates found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Templates found in Trash' ),
            'parent' => __( 'Parent Templates' ),
        ),
      'public' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ),
      'rewrite' => array('feeds' => false),
      'query_var' => true
    )
  );
}
```

but this has not resolved the issue.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Set it to `false` instead of `null`.

Comment: @rudtek, I made that change but the extra feed remained. There is no WP server cache installed, and I cleared my browser cache and did a hard refresh.

Comment: You may need to visit your permalinks page (settings/permalinks) to refresh rewrites.

Comment: Thanks, @rudtek, I resaved my permalinks, but the issue remains.

Comment: Ticket is already being generated related to [this topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185015/how-to-disable-a-custom-post-type-feed)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both answers to that question and unfortunately neither work.

Comment: When you want to link to another URL, surround the anchor text in square brackets, then immediately follow this with the URL in round brackets. You can see an example of this when typing questions or answers by clicking the Help link to the bottom right of the text editor.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191804/remove-a-certain-post-type-from-appearing-in-all-rss-feeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this post](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-disable-rss-feed/), I added

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3 );
```

to our child theme's `functions.php`.

Our SEO manager was okay with the fact this would remove feeds for categories as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you dive into how this works, you end up at [`set_props`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post_type/set_props/). At the bottom of that function you see that setting `rewrite' => array('feeds' => false)` will be interpreted as 'no rewriting', meaning the default will be used. Also, if you have not set the `has_archive` argument WP will not know what to fill the feed with. This is what leads to your 404's.

That said, what you need is a function that intercepts queries for `\feed\` before they lead to a 404. After all, you can't prevent people typing that url in their browser window, even if there would be a method to stop WP from generating it. So I'd do a check like this:

```
add_action ('template_redirect','wpse402292_redirect_feed');
function wpse402292_redirect_feed() {
  if (is_feed (array ('post','your-custom-post-type-name')))
     wp_redirect( home_url( '' ) ); // or somewhere else
  }
```

Comment: I would prefer the extra `feed` not to be present in the page. If it isn't present, I am happy with it generating a `404`. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Paste this in your functions.php and replace your-cpt slug.

```
function wpse_191804_pre_get_posts( $query ) 
{
  // only for feeds
  if( !$query->is_feed || !$query->is_main_query() )
    return query;

  $exclude = 'your-cpt';
  $post_types = $query->get('post_type');

  if (($key = array_search($exclude, $post_types)) !== false)
    unset($post_types[$key]);

    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );

    return $query;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_191804_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Where did you find that code from?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191804/remove-a-certain-post-type-from-appearing-in-all-rss-feeds

Comment: The problem in that post (I would like to remove all posts with a post type of nf_sub from showing up in any RSS feeds) is different to my problem (remove a custom post type's feed).